# Selected value in dropbox HTML

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I have the following code that programatically generates a dropdown box in php for me.

```
echo "<select name=\"choice\">";
echo "<option selected=\"selected\" disabled=\"disabled\">Number of Columns</option>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo "<option>$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

I need to use whatever item the user selects later but I'm not actually sure where the selected value is stored? I know this sounds silly but how do I access the selected item through HTML once the user has made a choice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use HTML to gather the value. HTML is an output language. You use either Javascript or PHP to access those items.

A jQuery Example would look like this:

```
<form action="submitToPhp.php">
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
        <option value='1'>first</option>
        <option value='2'>second</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script>
    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
        var selectedItem = $(this).val();
        alert(selectedItem);
        // Outputs the value of the selected dropdown
    });
</script>
```

A PHP version would be submitting that form to a PHP script:

```
<?php

$post = $_POST;

$selectedItem = $post['dropdown'];

echo $selectedItem;
// Outputs the value of the selected dropdown item
```

Comment: Ok thankyou I think I was looking for an implementation similar to the php example above but wasn't sure how to "get" the element if that makes sense ill test it out and mark the answer as correct otherwise ill come back for clarification.

Comment: I'm getting errors where 'dropdown' is not defined in my PHP (when declaring the selectedItem variable) I've made sure I've placed this code AFTER the create of the dropdown box, is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @gRnt Make sure that the name="" value in the <SELECT> item is what you are requesting in the PHP $_POST[''] code. Update your question with your new code so I can see what you have done

Answer (score 0):

You could always locate the select element through the parent form element.

eg:

```
alert(document.forms[0].choice.value);
```